# python re.findall to parse data between signature data, in hexdump file

Tags: python

Hi am trying to parse data from a hexdump file 'data.dat', which have the data

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

in which '0ff0a33a3aa3f00f' is the signature, i need to extract the data between each signature
result should be:
0000000000000028
0000000001000028313233340500060007000000
00000000020000280100000002000000
0000000003000028310002003300000004000000... etc

```
import binascii
import re
fo = open ('data.dat','rb+')
content = binascii.hexlify(fo.read())
match_object = re.findall(r'0ff0a33a3aa3f00f(\w*?)0ff0a33a3aa3f00f', content,re.M|re.I)
print match_object
```

but here am loosing data after every alternative signature

how to not include the rear signature out of match

Answer (score 3):

You could simply split the content:

```
content.split("0ff0a33a3aa3f00f")
```

result:

```
['', '0000000000000028', '0000000001000028313233340500060007000000', '00000000020000280100000002000000', '0000000003000028310002003300000004000000', '000000000400002801000000320002000100000032000000', '0000000000000030', '0000000001000030313233340500060007000000', '00000000020000300100000002000000', '0000000003000030310002003300000004000000', '000000000400003001000000320002000100000032000000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [forward lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or you'll consume the trailing signature, and thus one packet out of two (the last signature is consumed):

```
match_object = re.findall(r'0ff0a33a3aa3f00(\w*?)(?=0ff0a33a3aa3f00)', content,re.M|re.I)
print(match_object)
```

result:

```
['f0000000000000028', 'f0000000001000028313233340500060007000000', 
 'f00000000020000280100000002000000',
 'f0000000003000028310002003300000004000000',
 'f000000000400002801000000320002000100000032000000',
 'f0000000000000030', 'f0000000001000030313233340500060007000000',
 'f00000000020000300100000002000000',
 'f0000000003000030310002003300000004000000']
```

Note that the last data which is not wrapped by your signatures is not extracted. If you need that do:

```
re.findall(r'0ff0a33a3aa3f00(\w*?)(?=0ff0a33a3aa3f00|$)', content,re.M|re.I)
```

(trailing signature or end of text)

Comment: can u help if the signature is coming at the end, instead of starting , like this...................00000000000000280ff0a33a3aa3f00f00000000010000283132333405000600070000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f000000000200002801000000020000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f00000000030000283100020033000000040000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f0000000004000028010000003200020001000000320000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f00000000000000300ff0a33a3aa3f00f00000000010000303132333405000600070000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f000000000200003001000000020000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f00000000030000303100020033000000040000000ff0a33a3aa3f00f

Comment: 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
with signature 0ff0a33a3aa3f00f

Comment: still unicode crap in it: 233340500??0600070000000ff0a33a??3aa3f00f0000

Comment: sorry sir, i couldnt understand well. u can use the expression that i put in question , but remove first signature and add it at the end

Comment: my regex would work. But not with the unicode data you got from I don't know where.

Comment: your regex is working fine on first string. But i had to update the string to new format. only difference is that the '0ff0a33a3aa3f00f' at the beginning of string is moved to end . that format i updated in comments.
so now the first sub_string '0000000000000028' is getting omited
am using the code like this now..re.findall(r'(0ff0a33a3aa3f00f|$)(\w*?)(?=0ff0a33a3aa3f00f)'